# Using Crystal Report With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, crystal-reports-xi

Hello I am using Crystal report version 11.5.8.826, php version 7.0.10, Apache version 42.4.33 and MySql Version 5.7.14.
I have created the sampel rptone.rpt file that contents sample report. I want to load that rptone.rpt file using php.

With Crystal report 11.5.8.826, php 7.0.10, apache 42.4.33 and MySql 5.7.14 i have tried to connect/load crystal report file that is .rpt file using COM Object but it gives error

```
$my_report = "report/rptone.rpt";
$COM_Object = "CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1";
$objCom = new COM($COM_Object, "localhost", 0, "");
$crapp = $objCom->CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application");
$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($my_report, 1);
```

This expected to be open rptone.rpt file that must show the report but this gives error as:

> Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object
>   `CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1': Class not registered

Answer (score 0):

You may use to open the "crystal report.rpt" view in php by using iframe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).